# Serching by role mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to retrieve users based on role but with every role queried, I want to also retrieve admin too. I am not sure how to go about it. This is how I currently retrieve based on role

```
public async listAllStaffs(query: ListStaffsRequestQueryDTO) {
        var conditions = { }
        if (query.role) {
            conditions = { role: query.role, 'hub.id': query.merchant };
        } else {
            conditions = {'hub.id': query.merchant };
        }
        
        const data = { page: query.page, limit: query.limit, conditions: conditions};
        const all = await this.list(data);

        const pagination = {
            page: all.page,
            limit: all.limit,
            rowCount: all.rowCount,
            pageCount: all.pageCount
        };

        const staffs = all.staffs;
        return { staffs, pagination };
    }


async list(query: PaginationQuery): Promise<any> {
        const page = Number(query.page) - 1 || 0;
        let limit = Number(query.limit) || 20;
        const offset = page * limit;
        const sort = query.sort || 'createdAt';
        const archived = this.convertArchived(query.archived);

        const conditions = {
            ...query.conditions,
            ...(!archived
                ? { deletedAt: undefined }
                : { deletedAt: { $ne: undefined } })
        };

        const staffs = await this.model
            .find(conditions)
            .select(query.projections)
            .skip(offset)
            .limit(limit)
            .sort(sort);

        const totalDocuments = await this.model.countDocuments(conditions);
        const result = {
            staffs,
            page: Number(page) + 1,
            limit: Number(limit),
            rowCount: Number(totalDocuments),
            pageCount: Math.ceil(Number(totalDocuments) / limit)
        };

        return result;
    }
```

So if role is `operation` for example, I want to also return users with `admin`

So you have both operation staff and admin staff returned.

Comment: By admin, you mean `users` with `role` `admin`?

Comment: yes. so while the query is 'operations', I want to get users with role `admin` too

Comment: only for operations?

Comment: no, role query could be `finance` or `super-admin` or `waiter` or even `admin`

Comment: Cool, got your point

Answer (score 0):

Use `$in` operator, to look for `users` in multiple roles, like this:

```
if (query.role) {
      conditions = { role: { "$in": [query.role, "admin"] }, 'hub.id': query.merchant 
      };
 }
```

Comment: each user only have one role.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. This will return users with `admin` role and the one which you passed.